# Facebook plugin social, iframe does not adapt width to its parent

Tags: html, css, facebook

I'm trying to put a Facebook social plugin `<iframe>` in this [layout](https://jsfiddle.net/Orlandi_pw/x9udqytx/5/), but the problem is the content of this `<iframe>`, its not adapting to its parent width.

This is the `<iframe>` code:

```
<iframe id="fb-page" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?
   href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F505180683015806&tabs=timeline%2C%20messages&
   height=500&
   small_header=true&
   adapt_container_width=true&
   hide_cover=false&
   show_facepile=false" 
height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" ></iframe>
```

**Code altered just for better presentation of PHP parameters.*

As you can see, `adapt_container_width` is set to `true`, but nothing change, no matter the size of `wrapper` on page loading, always get width if passed in parameter or set width 340px, which is Facebook default value.

#### What was tested:

- Specify width value as a PHP parameter, results in a content with absolute width and can cause some overflow content to be hidden.
- Specify width with value '0' as a PHP parameter, results in a content with width 0px.
- Specify width with value '100%25' as a PHP parameter, results in a blank frame.
- Specify width with 100% on iframe element, don't change content width that will be always 340px (Facebook default value), or value defined via PHP parameter.

You can check with this fully functional [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Orlandi_pw/x9udqytx/5/), that already contain iframe code and HTML layout.

#### What I expect:

A way to make `<iframe>` content use 90% of its parent, instead of specify a absolute width and kill the responsiveness. And just use the `<iframe>` code that Facebook provide as option to render its content.

### Thanks in advance.

Comment: The FB social plugins aren't really responsive. At most you can get them to adapt to the initial width of the container at the time they are loaded, but don't expect them to properly resize when you change the window width. Setting the iframe width as a percentage won't help either, because the iframe content is set to take a certain width in pixels.

Comment: @CBroe, for me that ok if at least gets initial size of container when it load, but in this case, always get only width in PHP parameter (or a default value), and `adapt_container_width` does not its task. How to make this parameter works? Get parent width at load and set content width. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Same for me. The only solution I came up with is:

```
.fb-likebox {
    max-width: 288px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 288px;
}
```

with `overflow:hidden` at least doesn't make it look broken, but yes it does hide from the box.